# How to close a simulator window without closing all of them?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I'm using the iOS simulator on a Mac connected to Visual Studio for debugging a Xamarin app. I launched it for an iPhone and then for an iPad. Then I wanted to close the iPhone window only but couldn’t find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `File` / `Close Window` (CMD-W) to close the **current** window (i.e. each Simulator is running in its own window).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As well as File/Close as shown by @SushiHangover, with Bezels turned off (Menu:Window/Show Device Bezels) the red 'Close' button on each window also closes just that simulator:

[image]

(You can use Hardware/Device from the menu to check which simulators are currently active.)

Comment: You have to turn the device bezels off in order to get the window decorations to show (Xcode 9+)

Comment: @SushiHangover True, I turned those off so long ago I forgot they were a thing! Edited the answer to add this point.